# Click on "show more" image with selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

i would like to automate the click on the image "show 27 more" on this page "https://slotcatalog.com/en/The-Best-Slots" to extract the element of all items on each page until the last available page, with selenium.
The elements of the section are shown below:

[image: screeshot here]

which element should I click on?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add the code you've tried so far? I'd guess if you select the element via it's XPATH and then click on it, you should get desired result.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd most likely want to click on the a tag. As it contains the onclick function to load more.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('aAjaxSubmit').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[blk='gLoadMore']").click()
```

Now to loop it you could wrap it in a while True:

```
driver.get('https://slotcatalog.com/en/The-Best-Slots')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"cookie-ok"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"subs-close"))).click()

while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".aAjaxSubmit"))).click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        print('error')
        break
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, thats what i was looking for. As i mentioned tho, i was trying to load all the elements in the page and then to print the names of all items available, to get the final url to finally parse it with Beautiful soup im simply using "driver.current_url", but apparently it gives me the first 27 elements only. Is there any way to get all the elements after loading them all in the page? Im pretty new to webscraping so im not sure if this is the right approach either

Comment: think i solved it with "driver.page_source"